# How to create a segmentation chart with 'group' in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I have a datasets like this
[image]

And want to draw a segmentation chart similar like this [image]

This will be an example for one of the groups, so based on the dataset, I have groups A and B, I want to have two segmentation charts showing all the groups and each group will have its own segmentation chart showing each task start time and end time, and each task might appear multiple times in each group. I have the following code for showing group A, any suggestion to subplot group B also in the same chart? Basically is how to use the group column for compeleting the chart.
Right now the chart mix both groups A and B, but I want to distinguish them to have two separate segmentation chart

```
category <- c('task1', 'task2', 'task2','task1','task1')
start_min <- c(0, 0, 16, 45, 40)
stop_min <- c(14.9,18.8,17.5,65.5, 70)
group <- c('A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B')
data <- data.frame(category,start_min,stop_min,group)



task_bars <- ggplot(data, mapping=aes(ymin=0, ymax=1,
                                      xmin=start_min, xmax=stop_min,
                                      fill=as.factor(category),
                                      text=paste("Task:", str_wrap(string = category, width = 70,),
                                                 "<br>Start: ", format(start_min, digits=1), "min", 
                                                 "<br>Stop: ", format(stop_min, digits=1), "min")
)) +
  geom_rect(alpha=0.8) +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(
    axis.title.x=element_text(color="white"), axis.text.x=element_text(color="white"),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks=data$category)

task_bars <- plotly::ggplotly(proc_bars, tooltip="text", width = 970, height = 120) %>%
  plotly::config(displayModeBar = TRUE) %>% 
  plotly::layout(plot_bgcolor='black', paper_bgcolor='black', margin = list(b=30, l=0, r=10, t=30))

print(task_bars)
```

Comment: Please don't post images of data (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/)), asking us to transcribe what you already have appears lazy. Please post real data, either `data.frame(...)` code or the output from `dput(head(x,20))` (with just enough data to try a plot, no more). Thanks

Comment: `task_bars + facet_grid(group ~ .)`?

Comment: fyi, `proc_bars` is not found

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, yes, the proc_bars is task_bars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways come to mind. I'll show both the ggplot and plotly plots for each.

(FYI, I'm assuming `proc_bars` is really just the `task_bars` defined before it. If `proc_bars` is completely different, this may not apply.)

### Faceting

Changes

- adds `facet_grid(group ~ .)` to the plot

```r
library(ggplot2)
bars1 <- ggplot(data, mapping=aes(ymin=0, ymax=1, xmin=start_min, xmax=stop_min,
                                  fill=as.factor(category))) +
  geom_rect(alpha=0.8) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.title.x=element_text(color="white"), axis.text.x=element_text(color="white"),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank()) +
    scale_fill_discrete(breaks=data$category) +
  facet_grid(group ~ .)

plotly::ggplotly(bars1, tooltip="text", width = 970, height = 120) %>%
  plotly::config(displayModeBar = TRUE) %>% 
  plotly::layout(plot_bgcolor='black', paper_bgcolor='black', margin = list(b=30, l=0, r=10, t=30))
```

[image: ggplot2 of bars1]

[image: plotly of bars1]

### Move "group" to the y axis

This method changes to using `geom_tile`, placing `group` as the y-axis. The default is `height=1`, which would place the tiles touching in the middle; I'm setting `height=0.9` to mimic some spacing between them.

Changes:

- change from `geom_rect` to `geom_tile`, necessitating the addition of `xcenter` and `xwidth`
- comment out two theme elements so that the y-axis ticks show
- add `labs(y=NULL)` to hide the "group" y-axis name, over to you

```r
# this can be done without `dplyr` if desired
data2 <- dplyr::mutate(data, xwidth = stop_min - start_min, xcenter = start_min + xwidth/2)
bars2 <- ggplot(data2, mapping=aes(x=xcenter, y=group, width=xwidth, height=0.9, fill=as.factor(category))) +
  geom_tile(alpha=0.8) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.title.x=element_text(color="white"), axis.text.x=element_text(color="white"),
    # axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank()) +
  labs(y = NULL) +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks=data$category)

plotly::ggplotly(bars2, tooltip="text", width = 970, height = 120) %>%
  plotly::config(displayModeBar = TRUE) %>% 
  plotly::layout(plot_bgcolor='black', paper_bgcolor='black', margin = list(b=30, l=0, r=10, t=30))
```

[image: ggplot of bars2]

[image: plotly of bars2]

---

Notes:

- `ggplot2` will order the facets or y-ticks alphabetically; if you need the order to be anything different, change `group` to a `factor`, and you must explicitly control the `factor(group, levels=***)` levels component to be the order of unique values that you need.
- the order of groups is reversed between `bars1` and `bars2`; this is because in `bars1`, the facets are incrementing from top-to-bottom, so the "least" is on top; in `bars2`, the groups increment from bottom (y=1) to top (y=n), so the "least" is on bottom; there are several ways you might control this, including the `factor` note above

Comment: The faceting issue did works! And I also tried the second one which shows me the error "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (7): xmin, xmax and text
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. "

Comment: For your error, I don't know ... it works for me given this data (and my munging of `data`).